# making sure required parent webpage tags are included in a column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm working in Excel using Power Query to process some data for a website migration of ours. I have a table of webpages, with a column for tags of a specific type applied to the pages in the system. Our tags exist in a hierarchical structure. For this one type of tag, we need to make sure if a lower level tag is applied that its parent tags are also applied. I'm trying to figure out how to create a Power Query function to perform this check, and if a parent tag is missing then to add it.

Example tag structure: `content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-litigation-and-dispute-resolution/business-litigation/class-actions`

These are what we call content directory tags belonging to the business_law department are of the type practice-area. These practice area tags are the only ones I'm worried about here, and we have them in their own column, so we don't need to worry about any others.  These practice area tags are in a 3 level hierarchy.  In the above example, that is the level 3 tag class-actions. If that is found applied to the page, we would need to check to make sure both its level 2 parent `content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-litigation-and-dispute-resolution/business-litigation` and its level 1 parent `content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-litigation-and-dispute-resolution` are also applied to it.

We have two options for columns. Either all the practice area tags in one column comma-delimited, or them split into 10 separate columns of one tag each (or zero in some cases).

A correct example from a real page is:

```
content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-litigation-and-dispute-resolution/business-litigation/class-actions,content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-regulation-and-regulated-industries/banking-law,content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-litigation-and-dispute-resolution/dispute-resolution,content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-litigation-and-dispute-resolution,content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-litigation-and-dispute-resolution/business-litigation,content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-regulation-and-regulated-industries/consumer-finance,content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-regulation-and-regulated-industries,content_directories:business_law/practice-area/business-litigation-and-dispute-resolution/dispute-resolution/arbitration
```

If it somehow makes it easier, I can have a separate table listing out each possible tag, and then columns for tags that would be required in addition to it.

I also would like to note that the department will vary, but the rest of the structure remains essentially the same (just with different tags under practice-areas).

Answer (score 1):

First, I would take your table listing out each possible tag and the tags that would be required in addition to it, and convert it into a record where field names are tags and field values are lists of tags it implies *including* itself.

Maybe with something like:

```
let
  Source = YourTagTable,
  Names = Source[Tag],
  Values = Table.ToRows(Source),
  r = Record.FromList(
    Values,
    Names
  )
in
  r
```

Call that query "Implied Tags Record", and then you can take your comma-delimited strings and turn them into a list of all tags that ought to be there. For example, if you wanted to create a function query for this, it might be something like

```
(RawTags as nullable text) as nullable text =>
let
  lst = Text.Split(RawTags, ","),
  implied = List.Combine(
    List.Transform(
      lst,
      each let
        Name = Text.Trim(_)
      in
        Record.FieldOrDefault(
          #"Implied Tags Record",
          Name,
          {Name}
        )
    )
  ),
  Unique = List.Distinct(implied),
  Txt = Text.Combine(
    Unique,
    ","
  ),
  ret = if RawTags is null or RawTags = "" then
    RawTags
  else
    Txt
in
  ret
```

If you name this query "fEnhanceTags" then you can enhance your page table's Tags column with `Table.TransformColumns(#"Web Pages", {{"Tags", fEnhanceTags}})`